# Animations or Pictures of Group of Rigid Motions (or Rotations) of the Cube

Tags: group-theory, online-resources, visualization, math-software

Consider a cube that exactly fills a certain cubical box. As in Examples 8.7 and 8.10, the ways in which the cube
can be placed into the box corresponds to a certain group of permutations of the vertices of the cube. This is the group
of **group of rigid motions (or rotations) of the cube**. (It should not be confused with th e *group of symmetries
of the figure*, which will be discussed in the exercises of Section 12.) How many elements does this group have? Argue
geometrically that this group has at least three different subgroups of order 4 and at least four different subgroups of
order 3.

**[Hard Solution](http://math.hamline.edu/~wnk/courses/ma5890/week02/HW06.pdf)** Let the vertices of the cube be labeled by the lower case letters $a, b, ..., h$ and let the vertices (corners)
of the box be labeled by the upper case letters $A,B,...,H.$ We will use the word **vertex** to talk about the
verteces of the cube and the word **corner** to talk about the verteces of the box. The vertex $a$ can be placed at
any of the eight corners of the box. $\color{red}{\text{For each such placement, there are 3 different ways in which the cube can be
placed into the box.}}$ Hence there are 24 elements in the group of rigid motions (or rotations) of the cube.

Given a placement of the cube in the box, the rotations about a line joining the centers of opposite faces of the
cube constitute a subgroup of group of rigid motions (or rotations) of the cube.. Such a subgroup has 4
elements. Since there are three pairs of opposite faces, there are three such subgroups.

Given a placement of the cube in the box, the rotations of the cube about a line joining diagonally opposite
vertices constitute a subgroup of group of rigid motions (or rotations) of the cube. Such a subgroup has
3 elements. Since there are 4 such diagonally opposite vertices, there are 4 such subgroups.

[image]

Question 1. What's the most efficient way to visualize this? What program, software, or website can I use to visualize all these permutations? There has to be a better way than just plotting all these $24 \times 8 \times 8 $ points.

Question 2. Are there any animations? Is it easy to create one myself?

Question 3. I put this in red. I don't see why for each such placement, there are 3 different ways in which the cube can be placed into the box. Hypothetically assume I place vertex $a$ at vertex $A$ of the box. I choose $A$ for convenience. I can just call it something else. Because the box only has one opening or lid, there's only 1 way to place the cube into the box so that $a$ is at $A$?

This is from John B. Fraleigh page 86 exercise 8.45 A First Course in Abstract Algebra

**EDIT @aPaulT -** Could you please explain how you found this marvellous animation? I want to be able to do this in general for other shapes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an interactive graphic here if you don't mind installing the plugin:

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RotatingCubesAboutAxesOfSymmetry3DRotationIsNonAbelian/

Select "3b" for one of the rotations and drag the slider to see the cube move through the three positions with a corner in a fixed position for your Q3.

Comment: thanks. i upvoted for you.

Comment: I'm afraid I only found it by Googling "animation rotations of a cube" or something similar, so I don't have any idea where anything similar for other shapes might be found.